# Calling method, which calls other methods in Java

Tags: java

I am new in Java and I am interested if method `printMyProgress()` can be written without declaring any variables in it `(String name = "Nat"; int time=0;).`

```
public class Q7 {
String getMyName() {
  String name = "Nat";
    return name;  
}
int getMyTimeSoFar() {
    int time=0;
    return time;
}

 void printStudentProgress(String name, int time) {
     String minute ="";
     if (time==0||time>1) 
     minute = "minutes";
     else minute = "minute";
     print (name + " took " +time+ " "+  minute+" to reach Q7 in the Exam");     
 }

   void printMyProgress() {
       String name = "Nat";
       int time=0;
       printStudentProgress(name, time);  
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean like this? `printStudentProgress("Nat", 0);` ?

Comment: Did you have a try as you want?

Comment: Yes I tried but only can do it with declaring String name = "Nat" and int time=0 in the last method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; like this:

```
void printMyProgress() {
    printStudentProgress("Nat", 0);  
}
```

OR

```
void printMyProgress() {
    printStudentProgress(getMyName(), getTimeSoFar());  
}
```

Comment: it says "can't find symbol variable "Nat""

Comment: @user2943505 that doesn't make any sense to me... try looking at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Q7 {
    String getMyName() {
        return "Nat";  
    }
    int getMyTimeSoFar() {
        return 0;
    }

    void printStudentProgress(String name, int time) {
         String minute ="";
         if (time==0||time>1) 
          minute = "minutes";
         else 
          minute = "minute";
          System.out.println (name + " took " +time+ " "+  minute+" to reach Q7 in the Exam");     
    }

    void printMyProgress()
    {
     printStudentProgress(getMyName(), getMyTimeSoFar());  
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
       Q7 q7 = new Q7();

       q7.printMyProgress();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this method can be written without declaring any variables in it. You can declare your variables on a global scale:

```
public class Q7
{
    String name = "Nat";
    int time = 0;

    String getMyName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    int getMyTimeSoFar()
    {
        return time;
    }

    void printStudentProgress(String name, int time) 
    {
        String minute ="";

        if (time == 0 || time > 1) 
        {
            minute = "minutes";
        }
        else 
        {
            minute = "minute";
        }

        System.out.println(name + " took " + time + " " + minute + " to reach Q7 in the
            Exam");
    }

    void printMyProgress()
    {
        printStudentProgress(name, time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a global scale when declaring variables allows you to use them in your methods, rather than having to use instance variables for each method.